# Codename One: How to build Topbar background

Tags: codenameone

I'm a newbie of Codename one. I make a sample form with Command and Title.

It looks like in design: http://gyazo.com/3fc65e67cb7eb1efe91a007df46e8ae8

But when I run it on Simulator (iPhone 3gs skin), it looks like: http://gyazo.com/344856389fd9f69c7230f11bc8afda42

The top bar background is changed, but the bottom is not. And it seems 2 command (Cancel, Save) are out of topbar boundary: http://gyazo.com/800eb9450d547e413c2794af163fb14d

How can I keep the design of topbar? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the same UI with iOS 6 theme and iOS 7 theme matching the device style. You can customize this more in depth by using one of the builtin themes or hardcoding the platform themes. You can view the effects of the platform in the designer tool by selecting the native theme menu.

To learn about themeing you can follow the relevant tutorials in the [How Do I?](http://codenameone.com/how-do-i.html) section of the site.